# count of even numbers having more exponent of 2

Tags: algorithm, math, primes, prime-factoring

Suppose I have given a number n. I want to find out all then even numbers which are less than n, and also have a greater exponent of 2 in its prime factorization than that of the exponent of 2 in the prime factorization of n.

if n=18 answer is 4 i.e, 4,8,12,16.

Using a for loop from i=2 to less than n and checking for every i  will show time limit exceeded in the code.

My approach is to count no of times i will continue to divide by 2. But constraints of n=10^18. So, i think its a O (1) operation . Can anyone help me to find any formula or algorithm to find the answer as fast as possible?

Comment: You want to count how many number there are or you want to print all of them?

Comment: IIUC my answer should satisfy the solution your looking for

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to show how to get the count, with some examples at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

First assume *n* is an odd number. Obviously every even number less than *n* also has a greater exponent of 2 in its factorization, so the answer will be equal to (*n*−1) / 2.

Now suppose *n* is equal to 2 times some odd number *p*. There are (*p*−1) / 2 even numbers that are smaller than *p*, so it follows that there are also (*p*−1) / 2 numbers smaller than *n* that are divisible by at least 2<sup>2</sup>.

In general, given any number *n* that is equal to 2<sup>*k*</sup> times some odd number *q*, there will be (*q*−1) / 2 numbers that are smaller than *n* and have a larger exponent of 2 (> 2<sup>*k*</sup>) in their factorization.

So a function like this should work:

```py
def count_smaller_numbers_with_greater_power_of_2_as_a_factor(n):
    assert n > 0
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n >>= 1
    return (n-1) // 2
```

---

### Example 1 (*n* = 18)

1. Since *n* is even, keep dividing it by 2 until you get an odd number. This only takes one step (because *n* / 2 = 9)
2. Count the number of even numbers that are less than 9. This is equal to (9−1) / 2 = 4

### Example 2 (*n* = 10<sup>18</sup>)

1. In this case, *n* = 2<sup>18</sup> × 5<sup>18</sup>. So if we keep halving *n* until we get an odd number, the result will be 5<sup>18</sup>.
2. The number of even numbers that are less than 5<sup>18</sup> is equal to (5<sup>18</sup>−1) / 2 = 1907348632812

Comment: can u please give an example by taking n=18

Comment: Assuming two’s complement, in C and languages with similar operators, this can be expressed as `n / (n & -n) / 2`. (`n & -n` finds the greatest power of two that divides `n`, since the only bit set in `n` and its two’s complement is the trailing one bit.)

Comment: Testing this, this seems to work very well on numbers that are not powers of 2, but on powers of 2 it does not give the correct answer. You can use len(findevennumberswithexponentgreaterthan2lessthannum(num)) on my answer to test against. For numbers like 670, it gives the correct answer,  which is 167. But for powers of two, it does not. For example the len of the actual 10000 should be 2500, but the equation here has answer 312.  or for 100 the correct answer is 25, but this equation gives 12. Just wanted to point out it works on numbers other than powers of 2.

Comment: @oppressionslayer if I understand the OP correctly, the problem is to count all the numbers below a certain limit whose factors have a *greater* power of 2. So for example since 100 = 25×4, the function should output the number of integers below 100 that are divisible by 8. So the correct answer is 12. For any power of 2, the function should output zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your division is limited by constant number 64 (for 10^18~2^64), and O(64)=O(1) in complexity theory.

Number of two's in value factorization is equal to the number of trailing zero bits in binary representation of this value, so you can use bit operations (like `& 1` and right shift `shr, >>`) to accelerate code a bit or apply some [bit tricks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightBinSearch)

Answer (score 0):

First, suppose `n = 2^k * something`. Find out `k`:

```
long k = 0;
while(n % 2 == 0) { n >>= 1; k++; }
n <<= k;
```

Now that you know who is `k`, multiply `2^k` by 2 to get the first power of 2 greater than `2^k`:

```
long next_power = 1 << (k + 1);  // same as 2^(k + 1)
```

And lastly, check if `n` is odd. If it isn't, print all the multiples of `next_power`:

```
if(k == 0){  //equivalent to testing n % 2 == 0
    for(long i = next_power; i < n; i += next_power) cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

---

**EXAMPLE: n = 18**

`k` will be 1, because 18 = 2^1 * 9 and the `while` will finish there.

`next_power` will be 4 (= `1 << (k + 1)` = `2 ^ (k + 1)`).

`for(long i = next_power; i < n; i += next_power) cout<<i<<endl;` will print 4, 8, 12 and 16.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do with a gcd trick i found:

```
You can find the count by //4. So 10^18 has 
  In [298]: pow(10,18)//4                                                                                                                                                                            
  Out[298]: 250000000000000000

You can find the count of 18 by //4 which is 4

Fan any numbers that meet your criteria. You can check by using my 
algorithm here, and taking the len of the array and conpare with the 
number div//4 to see that that is the answer your looking for: an exact 
match. You'll notice that it's every four numbers that don't have an 
exponent of 2. So the count of numbers can be found with //4. 

import math

def lars_last_modulus_powers_of_two(hm):
   return math.gcd(hm, 1<<hm.bit_length())

def findevennumberswithexponentgreaterthan2lessthannum(hm):
    if hm %2 != 0:
      return "only for use of even numbers"
    vv = []
    for x in range(hm,1,-2):
       if  lars_last_modulus_powers_of_two(x) != 2:
          vv.append(x)
    return vv
```

Result:

```
In [3132]: findevennumberswithexponentgreaterthan2lessthannum(18)                                                                                                      
Out[3132]: [16, 12, 8, 4]
```

This is the fastest way to do it as you skip the mod down the path to get the answer. Instantly get the number you need with lars_last_modulus_powers_of_two(num) which is one operation per number.

Here is some example to show the answer is right:

```
In [302]: len(findevennumberswithexponentgreaterthan2lessthannum(100))                                                                                                                             
Out[302]: 25

In [303]: 100//4                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[303]: 25

In [304]: len(findevennumberswithexponentgreaterthan2lessthannum(1000))                                                                                                                            
Out[304]: 250

In [305]: 1000//4                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[305]: 250

In [306]: len(findevennumberswithexponentgreaterthan2lessthannum(23424))                                                                                                                           
Out[306]: 5856

In [307]: 23424//4                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[307]: 5856
```

Comment: I also include a few ways to reduce numbers without prime factorization in the code located here if it's of interest to what your doing: https://github.com/oppressionslayer/primalitytest